# ACL in the Controller vs URL patterns

Tags: authentication, symfony

In the Symfony 2 Docs

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
```

This looks like it could have ***multiple different*** `form_login`'s? Is pattern required? If I define my ACL in controller actions like:

```
/**
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
 */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    // ...
}
```

Do I still need the pattern? Also which `login_path` and `check_path` will this (annotations) lead to, supposing there are multiple definitions of `login_form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple `form_login`'s. What you can have is multiple `firewall`s. Each `firewall` can then contain a `pattern` and the `form_login` etc. `pattern` is required for each `firewall`. The annotations will lead to the `login_path` and `check_path` of the relevant `firewall` (relevant `firewall` being the one whose `pattern` matches the URL in question).